# Cordova Plugins Photo Library Plugin: Get downloaded picture file_uri path

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova Plugins Photo Library Plugin to download picture from server or internet. I successfully downloaded picture from internet and server. However, I fail to get the path of picture. I need the file_uri path so that I can display the picture by showing the file_uri path.

The following is my code.

```
 var url = 'https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/am9znpv_700b.jpg'; 
    var album = 'DRDMChat';
    cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(url, album, 
        function (libraryItem) {
            var ImagePath = libraryItem.cdvphotolibrary
            alert(libraryItem.cdvphotolibrary);
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the path to the photo using the `photoURL` attribute of `libraryItem`.

Here is the code -

```
var url = 'https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/am9znpv_700b.jpg'; 
var album = 'DRDMChat';
cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(url, album, 
    function (libraryItem) {

        //log or alert the below attributes
        console.log(libraryItem.id);          // ID of the photo 
        console.log(libraryItem.photoURL);    // Cross-platform access to photo 
        console.log(libraryItem.thumbnailURL);// Cross-platform access to thumbnail 
        console.log(libraryItem.fileName);

        var ImagePath = libraryItem.photoURL //Photo URL Access
        alert(libraryItem.photoURL);
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
```

Refer [Displaying photos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-photo-library#displaying-photos) Section of `cordova-plugin-photo-library` for other attributes of `libraryItem`.